# Confusing class and method call in OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart, magic-methods

I have a framework (OpenCart) Controller class (like: catalog/controller/product/product.php) the code looks like:

```
class ControllerProductProduct extends Controller {
    public function index() {
      //some code
      $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
      //some more code
    }
}
```

there is an expression like `$this->response->setOutput($this->render());`. I know what this expression is used for, but I am pretty confused in how it works.

`$this` refers to current class i.e. `ControllerProductProduct`, it means `$this->response` object must exist in either `ControllerProductProduct` or its parent class `Controller`. But this is not the case. This object actually exists in a protected property of parent class `Controller` as `Controller::registry->data['response']->setOutput()`. So shouldn't it say like:

```
$this->registry->data['response']->setOutput();
```

instead of
    $this->response->setOutput();

I am also giving a snippet of `Controller` class so you can have idea.

```
abstract class Controller {
    protected $registry;    
    //Other Properties
    public function __construct($registry) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }
    public function __get($key) {
        //get() returns registry->data[$key];
        return $this->registry->get($key);
    }
    public function __set($key, $value) {
        $this->registry->set($key, $value);
    }
    //Other methods
}
```

I've no clue how this expression is working? Any idea how this is possible?

Thanks.

Comment: I kind of having the same trouble with exception of there is no __get method declared and it can also be used ,see:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23183327/dynamically-adding-new-properties-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working very easily using *magic methods* `__get()` and `__set()`.

If You are trying to get an inaccessible class variable (e.g. that is not declared) a magic `__get('property_name')` method is invoked.

Thus when You are trying to retrieve `$response`, a magic method `__get()` is called and `$this->registry->get('response')` is returned instead (as there is no `$response` property declared).

Yes, You could write `$this->registry->get('response')->setOutput($this->render());` instead, but this would be of not much use and more writing. It is OK to let the PHP retrieve the variable using it's `__get()` method, though it is not so clean.

Anyway, there is nothing wrong with the solution.

EDIT: a little bit cleaner solution would be this:

```
class Controller {
    //...
    function getResponse() {
        return $this->registry->get('response');
    }
    //...
}
```

Then You could call a concrete method in Your code and it would be clear enough:

```
class ControllerProductProduct extends Controller {
    public function index()
        //...
        $this->getResponse()->setOutput($this->render());
    }
}
```

But this would mean that there would be a need of `getXYZ` method for each possible property while `__get()` allows You to extend the `$registry` with no further work needed (in the case I described if You would add another property to `$register` You would have to add another `getProperty()` method - but still this would be more clear/clean solution).

Answer (score 0):

This magic called "overloading".
 
Here it is smaller demo:

```
<?php

class PropsDemo 
{
    private $registry = array();

    public function __set($key, $value) {
        $this->registry[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function __get($key) {
        return $this->registry[$key];
    }
}

$pd = new PropsDemo;
$pd->a = 1;
echo $pd->a;
```

Look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php. It's explained clearly enough.