# Dynamically adding new properties in php?

Tags: php, opencart

I've recently read the opencart source code,finding this code that seems odd to me

```
class Customer {
    private $customer_id;
    private $firstname;
    private $lastname;
    private $email;
    private $telephone;
    private $fax;
    private $newsletter;
    private $customer_group_id;
    private $address_id;

    public function __construct($registry) {
        $this->config = $registry->get('config');//no config property in the class
        $this->db = $registry->get('db');//no db property in the class
```

How is it possible to use $this->(none existence property) to add new properties?And if it does,what is the pros to use this approach instead of using the common way to declare these properties in the class like

```
    private $config;
    private $db;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This a bug. PHP *allows* you to use properties you haven't declared.

Both `$config` and `$db` will be public, because that is the default declaration.

There is no good reason to use undeclared properties.

---

This class looks poorly designed. The input is a `registry` but it only needs `"config"` and `"db"`, so why isn't the signature:

```
public function __construct(DB $db, Config $config)
```

You can also wonder whether an object named `Customer` (which looks like a data wrapper) should be given a `DB` object.

Based on all the other private variables there doesn't actually seem any use for `$db` and `$config` because it's all just flat data.

Comment: Thank you!Then what is the point of using this bug.I think the author pass an entire object to the class should has his reasons,because this is a well known shopping cart,just wondering why.

Comment: I think this stems from when classes were first introduced in PHP 4. The early implementations were not very strict. The strictness is only slowly being turned up to avoid old code from breaking. IDEs that do code analysis will catch this bug for you, so not much of a concern.

Comment: OpenCart does actually use the `$db` object at a later point in the code, and the reason it's set is so that the `login()` method can use `$this->db` without having to pass it the DB object each time. That said, there's no reason why the class couldn't set those properties initially in the same manner `$customer_id` etc have been, and then assign it

Comment: I guess it's just poor design all the way through then. A `login` function shouldn't need a `$db` as an argument. The `$db` argument should be passed to an `Authentication` entity in the constructor, at least, that's one way to do it. The somehow the `Customer` needs to authenticate something then pass it the `Authentication` object. Opencraft is not the pinacle of OO-design. It uses objects, but is not designed with OO in mind.